# application guide screens in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, splash-screen

I am aware of the Startup Splash screens in Android which I have used in my application during initial resource load.

In additional to the splash screen, I have 3 screens which shows a basic guide or tutorial of what the application is about. I need these screens to come only during first installation. Otherwise, these screens should not come. Any help with tutorial or steps to do is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a flag in your shared preference, and after showing the tutorial for the first time you can set it to true. Every time when the app launches check for this flag, if the flag is set true then dont show the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. +1 :) Yeah, I didn't think about that shared preferences :D :D

Comment: @Spidey Please accept the answer if it had solved your problem ;)

Comment: Sorry, I had to wait for 15 mins anyways... Thanks