# Create tour guide in android application using images of the application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Okay I have gone through several posts and libraries like :-

[Create guided tour in an Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129901/create-guided-tour-in-an-android-app)

[application guide screens in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851493/application-guide-screens-in-android)

And I have found some good libraries for creating tour guide. Some of the very good libraries I found are :-

TourGuide https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide and

ShowCase https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView

But the one thing that these differ from my requirements are they can be used over view components like buttons or textviews of the actual view of the application. But what I want to do is use screenshots of the application instead of the actual view components.

So while using these libraries, I cannot point out a particular view component which should be used to show the tour guide.

My question is :- Is there any way I can use these libraries for my requirements? Is there any other methods  that I can use to create the tour guide using screen shots?

Thank you.

Comment: Screenshot == `ImageView`... I don't see why those libraries won't work.

Comment: Yes you are right but how would I point out to a particular location inside the screenshot to a button ??

Comment: As you can see on the screenshot here, there is actually a button where I can point out to focus on it. But in my case the whole app screen is one component i.e an imageview   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/worker8/all_my_media_files/d0b17ba/2015-07-01_screenshot2.png

Comment: Personally, I would just take the screenshots yourself, then have ImageViews be the actual showcase

Comment: This is what I am trying to do bro, this is what I am trying.

Comment: I said without `ShowcaseView`. You can take screenshosts very easily. http://lifehacker.com/5994516/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-android You can add "circles" using photoshop, or something

Comment: The problem with your approach in my case is that I want to switch to another image only when the user taps on the particular section which is focused. If I use a photoshopped image, user could tap anywhere and next image will be shown.

Comment: You can set a `onTouchListener` to only capture a section of the screen... Not 100% reliable, sure, but it is possible :) I understand what you mean, though

Comment: Thank you bro I will take into account your idea.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other methods that I can use to create the tour guide using screen shots?

Since you are using images to construct the app tour, I believe **ImageSwitcher** would be your solution, in case you would like to develop this module yourself.

> Is there any way I can use these libraries for my requirements?

Otherwise you may try [AppIntro](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro), a clean and simple to use library that allow your to create the app intro by fragments, images, etc.

And since it is an image, so you may not be able to set a focus over a view components like the libraries you found and mentioned in your question. You would require to edit the image in any image editor such as Adobe Photoshop to add the focus or click effect on the image before you apply it in the AppIntro.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I appreciate. But the problen with this approach in my case is that I want to switch to another image only when the user taps on the particular section which is focused. If I use a photoshopped image, user could tap anywhere and next image will be shown

Comment: @Viper, this could be achieved with the AppIntro library as well, in this case you need to create fragments which a fragment with show the screenshot as the layout's background, and apply an overlay ImageButton with an image of transparently clicking effect in the particular section which you would like the user to click and navigate next.

Comment: That is a really good idea I appreciate. I created an image with the same size as the screenshot. cropped the portion that I want the user to select and made rest of the portion transparent. The comes another problem that click event should execute only when the user taps on the cropped portion. As the image is the same size as the screenshot, the tap option executes even when the user taps on other parts of the screen and not only on the cropped image. How would I solve this problem.